# Add custom token in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, internationalization, joomla2.5, token

I need to add a custom token in this JS script, when using Joomla 2.5. What is the correct way to add a token? This (`**CUSTOM_TOKEN**`) doesn't work and I can't find relevant documentation about this.

I don't know if is relevant, bus I am using the language manager and the section Overrides to add the string value.

```
if (element) {
    $('.content').after('<div><a id="scrollUp" href="#">▲</a><a id="scrollDown" href="#">▼</a></div><span>'**CUSTOM_TOKEN**'</span>');
}
```

Comment: So you want to translate / use a language token into JavaScript?

Comment: @ValentinDespa, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Load the Joomla JavaScript framework**

```
<?php
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

**Make string available to Javascript** (you need to define all strings you want to use (I don't know if it's somehow possible to load them all. I just needed 2-3 so I didn't bother to search further.

```
JText::script('COM_HELLOWORLD_TEXT_DEMO');
```

**Use it in JavaScript**

```
Joomla.JText._('COM_HELLOWORLD_TEXT_DEMO')
```

I've seen once a docu page with this stuff, but I can't seem to find it how.

Let me know if this helps.